# Journey builder : how to send an email only on spring and summer?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I hope you are well.

In Journey builder, I was wondering if it is possible to schedule an email activity (= email sending) only during spring and summer, and not during autumn and winter.

Is it possible ?
Thank you,
François

Comment: Have you looked into exclusion scripts?

Comment: ...it all comes down to your entry event. If it's an automation, you could just check current month in your SQL and return no records, if it is autumn/winter.

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think I will add a column "springsummer" in my target DE and I will indicate "yes" or "no" value (= value calculated from the SQL Query that will populate the target DE). And then I will add a decision split in my journey so I Can only send the email to recipients that will have a "yes" in the "springsummer" column.